# Conditional value bolding or annotation for a barplot

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

The following query generates a barplot for top tickers:

```
df2=final_df.groupby(['ticker'])['ticker'].count().rename(columns={'ticker':''}).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'number_tickers_uploaded'}).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
sns.set(style='darkgrid')
plt.title('Top tickers uploaded in the last week')
result = df2.sort_values('number_tickers_uploaded',ascending=False)
sns.barplot(x='ticker', y='number_tickers_uploaded', data=result.head(8), palette='Set2')
```

This a sample of the data:

```
        ticker    number_tickers_uploaded  
0       BWM       50     
1       IND       25     
2       RIA       18    
3       X         10   
4       Y         6
```

The resulting barplot lists tickers by number_tickers_uploaded in descending order, but I would like the value to be bolded (either the ticker or the bar itself) and annotated with let's say "Z Fund," if it is equal to x or y .

Thank you!

--Edit--

I know I can annotate like so:

```
# Annotate with text + Arrow
plt.annotate(
# Label and coordinate
'Z Fund', xy=(25, 50), xytext=(0, 80),

# Custom arrow
arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05)
)
```

But I am trying to annotate conditionally (before you know the position the arrow and annotation should go)- not after seeing the data is plotted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a bit chaotic and I'm having problems understanding what you want to do under which conditions. As far as I understand, the aim is to make the ticklabels bold, add an annotation with an arrow and have an edge on bars for those bars which belong to some special label. The following code does that:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"name" : list("ABCDXY"), "value" : [5,6,3,5,7,4]})
result = df.sort_values("value",ascending=False)

ax = sns.barplot(x="name", y="value", data=result, palette='Set2')


for i,t in enumerate(ax.get_xticklabels()):
    if t.get_text() in ["X", "Y"]:
        ## bold ticklabels
        t.set_weight("bold")
        ## bar edges
        ax.patches[i].set_edgecolor("k")
        ax.patches[i].set_linewidth(2)
        ## arrow annotations
        ax.annotate("Z Fund",(i, ax.patches[i].get_height()), 
                    xytext=(0,30), textcoords='offset points', ha="center",
                    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is better than I could hope for. I wish I could upvote this more than once lol. Thanks alot!

Comment: actually small problem, my x and y are right next to each other so the annotation overlaps. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Sure, maybe you want to rotate the label? Or make its font smaller? Or make one label above and the other below, such that they don't meet up?

Comment: Sorry the issue is not with label- it is with an overlapping annotation, since column Y comes after column X. So Z Fund is on top of Z Fund. Any method works

Comment: Haha but how? How do I for example conditionally make one annotation above the other if the label position is 1 before or 1 after the next label in get_text()?

Comment: e.g. `xytext=(0,(-1)**i*30)`